# I am trying to load a csv file into MS Access Table

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am loading an access database using VB macro from a CSV file. After the load is successfull I find that the leading zeroes are removed. I have set the field as text and using Docmd.transfertext method to load the data.
Is there any way to prevent access from removing the leading zeroes.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although the *destination* field may be set as `Text`, during the import Access has to determine the type of the *source* field. And that is done automatically: If everything can be converted to a number Access assumes it *is* a number and converts it accordingly, omitting all leading zeros. Only *then* this value is written to the table and converted to text again, but the zeros are long gone.

You'll need to explicitly define the source field as `Text`. The easiest way probably is to create an import specification. This has to be done only once for your Access database. After that you can use its name as the second parameter to all calls to `DoCmd.TransferText`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35344306/6216216 for how to create an import specification.

Comment: Yes. I created a specification and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @Amrit: Great, glad I could help. If this answers your question then mark it as the accepted answer.