# Excel VBA ADO Cutting Decimals (Possible Bug in ADO?)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado, adodb

Can anybody help me with this please?

**The problem**:
I have the below code in a module which works perfectly usually, but when i run it on [this sample file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BygwXrk7-L67WW9xRnFFdm9nSlRYb2h2eE1lNWtTUjl0cWFF), I noticed that the decimals in the "Upper Limit" (column D) are cut.

**A temporary solution i found** was that i had to modify in the sample file the upper limit from 1 to 1.0 (so to add ".0" at the end) at line 26 to make it look like a decimal number. After this the decimals were imported correctly on the sheet. But, this is not a solution.

*I'm using*:
Excel 2013 (15.0.5111.1000) 32-bit (office package is: MS Office Standard 2013) and the following libraries enabled [image: (screenshot of libraries)]

**How to reproduce**:

1. Put the below code in a module and run it on the sample file
2. Notice column D. Starting from line 6 all decimals are cut. You will
   see only integers.
3. Now, open the sample file (in Notepad++ for example), and modify the
   upper limit value in line 26 from "1" to "1.0", then save it.
   [image: (screenshot of line 26)]
4. Run the below code again on the modified sample file and notice in
   column D (Upper Limit) that starting from line 6 all decimals
   appear.

Any idea why this happens?

```vb
Sub ADODB_Import_CSV()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.Clear

Dim Connection As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Recordset As New ADODB.Recordset

On Error Resume Next
ChDrive ThisWorkbook.Path
ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
On Error GoTo 0

ImportedFileFullPath = Application.GetOpenFilename
If ImportedFileFullPath = False Then Exit Sub
ImportedFileDirPath = Mid(ImportedFileFullPath, 1, InStrRev(ImportedFileFullPath, "\"))
ImportedFileName = Mid(ImportedFileFullPath, InStrRev(ImportedFileFullPath, "\") + 1, Len(ImportedFileFullPath))

Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & ImportedFileDirPath & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""
strSQL = "SELECT Trim(TestCodeDescription)," & _
                    "Cdbl(NumbericMeasure) AS Measurements," & _
                    "Cdbl(LowerLimit) AS LowerLimit," & _
                    "Cdbl(UpperLimit) AS UpperLimit" & _
             " " & _
             "FROM [" & ImportedFileName & "]" & _
             " " & _
             "WHERE (IsNumeric(LowerLimit) AND IsNumeric(UpperLimit) AND IsNumeric(NumbericMeasure) AND LowerLimit<>UpperLimit AND IsDate(EventDateTime1))"

Connection.Open Provider
Recordset.Open strSQL, Connection

For i = 0 To Recordset.Fields.Count - 1
    Cells(1, i + 1).Value = Recordset.Fields(i).Name
Next i

With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset Recordset
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter
    .Columns.AutoFit
End With
Recordset.Close: Set Recordset = Nothing: Connection.Close: Set Connection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the sample file please, I cant access the links.

Comment: Hmm, i shared it in google drive. It should be accessible. I don't know, maybe it works in internet explorer?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BygwXrk7-L67WW9xRnFFdm9nSlRYb2h2eE1lNWtTUjl0cWFF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't have access as at work.

Comment: Yeah, i also don't have access at work to GDrive.. any suggestion where should i upload it then?

Comment: Just show a screen shot of data that's going ok, and what's not.  Don't need the whole file.

Comment: There is a lot of data in that file, even if screenshot the relevant part, with two huge screenshots I'm afraid i would ruin the whole post because it would become unreadable.

Comment: We only need a small sample for the problem numbers. How large are these numbers is not immediately clear. Please actually post as text in body and not a screenshot [because...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451). This sets up a [MCVE]. GDrive links will break in the future unhelpful for future readers.

Comment: Hi, so this is very interesting. I've extracted a few lines from the sample file to copy it here, but before I put it here, i run the test again and the decimals weren't cut. 
So.. this bug drives me nuts :).
Because I have a characters limitation in comment , i will put the sample in my next comment, but please create a CSV file where you add 25 lines from this first:

[)>06P1PRT-10074232P1.16P1S178411904001,2/18/2019 11:07,1141433,2000.10 - Measurement SE_Supply7 resistance,1837.9,10,10

after which you add the sample from my next comment.

Comment: The sample:
SerialNumberCustomer,EventDateTime1,EquipmentName,TestCodeDescription,NumbericMeasure,LowerLimit,UpperLimit
[)>06P1PRT-10074232P1.16P1S178411904001,2/18/2019 11:07,1141433,2040.02 - Measure the current consumption,0.41012,0.15,1
[)>06P1PRT-10074232P1.16P1S178411904001,2/18/2019 11:07,1141433,2060.03 - Measure SE_Output1,4.954,4.8,5.253
[)>06P1PRT-10074232P1.16P1S178411904001,2/18/2019 11:07,1141433,2060.04 - Measure SE_Output2,4.9535,4.8,5.253
[)>06P1PRT-10074232P1.16P1S178411904001,2/18/2019 11:07,1141433,2060.05 - Measure SE_Output3,4.9745,4.8,5.253

Comment: It's not a "bug" but just the way the text drivers tend to work, and it's well-documented.  A text file has no column metadata to describe the datatypes in each column, so the driver "samples" the first x rows to guess the type for each column.  In your first case it finds only integers, so it assigns that field as Integer/Long and and decimals lower down in the file get coerced to that type.  Adding a decimal at the top of the file prevents that.  **EDIT:** missed @DStanley's post but that also explains the issue.

Comment: @TimWilliams My answer assumed importing from _excel_, not a CSV. But the root problem is similar. The right answer is to either configure the driver to treat everything as strings or use a metadata file that defines the column types.

Comment: If you want to specify datatypes for each field you can use a `schema.ini` file - see eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209804/schema-ini-file-not-working-for-ms-access

Comment: Hmm, ok i'll try it and reply. I hope it'll work. Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody this solved the problem.

So it turned out that the solution is to create a "schema.ini" file in the same folder as my CSV file which is processed by ADO.

I created the ini file with the following lines and the issue is now gone.

```
[sample file for analysis.csv]
Format=CSVDelimited
Col1=SerialNumberCustomer Text
Col2=EventDateTime1 DateTime
Col3=EquipmentName Text
Col4=TestCodeDescription Text
Col5=NumbericMeasure Double
Col6=LowerLimit Double
Col7=UpperLimit Double
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. SQL delivered decimals but recordset returned values with no decimals.

Solution: In my SQL I used `CAST(fieldname as Double)` and then it worked fine. Data types like Decimal(15,6), Float DID NOT WORK. A bit frustration before I found this.